# Calling FINGERPRINT_premain on more c++ compiler/platforms

Tags: c++, openssl, fips

I am trying to use a statically link OpenSSL in FIPS mode on IBM PLinux using xlC_r as the compiler/linker.  This combination is not supported by fipsld or fips_premain.c.  fipld will add linker options to call FINGERPRINT_premain on uname -s in {OSF1, IRIX, HP-UX, AIX, Darwin}, fips_premain.c will do compiler specific solutions for gcc, cl(Microsoft), cc(SUN), and some others that I am not familiar with.  Unfortunately xlC_r on IBM PLinux is not covered by either of those so I would like to know if adding the following code to one of my cpp files is acceptable for FIPS validation or if I need to change my compiler/linker to gcc or is there another way(linker options?) to keep xlC_r.  Please include some justification.

```
#if defined(PREMAIN_NOT_COVERED)
extern "C" void FINGERPRINT_premain(void);

class FIPSInitializer
{
public:
    FIPSInitializer()
    {
        FINGERPRINT_premain();
    }
    virtual ~FIPSInitializer()
    {
    }
};
extern FIPSInitializer fips_initializer;
FIPSInitializer fips_initializer;
#endif
```

I also tried using -Wl,init,FINGERPRINT_premain while linking, but then our test would segfault while using our shared library.

OpenSSL User Guide:
http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-1.1.1.pdf

OpenSSL Security Policy:
http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> so I would like to know if adding the following code to
>   one of my cpp files is acceptable for FIPS validation

```
class FIPSInitializer
{
public:
    FIPSInitializer()
    {
        FINGERPRINT_premain();
    }
    virtual ~FIPSInitializer()
    {
    }
};
```

Hmmm... this sounds odd. The only way to enter FIPS mode is though `FIPS_mode_set`. If you call `FIPS_mode_set` and it returns non-zero, then you are using validated cryptography. If you call `FIPS_mode_set` and it fails, then you will still be able to encrypt and decrypt (think a "pluggable" architecture) but you will *not* be using validated cryptography. See [*FIPS mode set*](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_mode_set%28%29) for details.

Just speculation: if `FIPS_mode_set` fails and `FINGERPRINT_premain` is not called, then you probably deviated from the procedures required by the [*OpenSSL FIPS 140-2 Security Policy*](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.pdf%E2%80%8E).

---

> fips_premain.c will do compiler specific solutions for gcc, cl(Microsoft),
>   cl(Microsoft), cc(SUN), and some others that I am not familiar with...

You do not compile `fips_premain.c`. Its compiled when you build the FIPS Object Module or link against the the FIPS Object Module. There's even been talk about removing it altogether.

Anything other than below invalidates the FIPS build procedure, and you will not be using validated cryptography.

```
$ export OPENSSL_INSTALLDIR=/usr/local/ssl/darwin
$ cd openssl-fips-2.0.5/
$ ./config
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The result of the above is `fipscanister.o` and friends. You can find them (there's four of them) in `$OPENSSL_INSTALLDIR\lib`:

```
$ ls /usr/local/ssl/darwin/lib/
fipscanister.o              fips_premain.c
fipscanister.o.sha1         fips_premain.c.sha1
```

After you build and install the FIPS Object Module, you then build the FIPS Capable Library. You are free to turn knobs for the FIPS Capable Library, as long as it does not jeopardize the hallowed `fipscanister.o` and friends.Note the use of **`fips`** with `config`.

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.1e/
$ ./config fips shared -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw -no-engine \
  --openssldir=$OPENSSL_INSTALLDIR \
  --with-fipsdir=$OPENSSL_INSTALLDIR \
  --with-fipslibdir=$OPENSSL_INSTALLDIR/lib/

$ make depend
$ make all
$ sudo -E make install
```

You have to use `-E` because `install` also builds components (shame on OpenSSL). During install, I believe the shared object will be linked against the hallowed `fipscanister.o`. After linking, the modules signature will be embedded in the resulting executable by `fipsld`. `fipsld` is used by the OpenSSL build process, and internally calls a program called `incore`. `incore` writes the actual signature.

---

When it comes time to build your FIPS validated executable or shared object, you will perform the following:

```
$ export CC=`find $OPENSSL_INSTALLDIR -name fipsld`
$ echo $CC 
/usr/local/ssl/darwin/bin/fipsld
$ export FIPSLD_CC=`find /usr/bin -iname gcc`
$ echo $FIPSLD_CC 
/usr/bin/gcc

# Now build your project via make (or though the command line):
$ make
...
```

When your makefile invokes `LD`, its really invoking OpenSSL's `fipsld`. `fipsld` will ensure your program links against `fipspremain.o`, and internally calls a program called `incore`. `incore` writes the actual signature to your executable or shared object. The following is from `openssl-fips-2.0.5` makefile:

```
fips_premain_dso$(EXE_EXT): fips_premain.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DFINGERPRINT_PREMAIN_DSO_LOAD -o $@ fips_premain.c \
        $(FIPSLIBDIR)fipscanister.o ../libcrypto.a $(EX_LIBS)
```

If you don't have `fipsld` installed, you can find it in, for example, `openssl-fips-2.0.5`. Just copy it into `$OPENSSL_INSTALLDIR\bin`. I don't recall if `make install` copies it (and I seem to recall filing a bug report about it).

You cannot embed a signature in a static library. OpenSSL could not do it when it built `libcrypto.a`, and you cannot do it when you build `libmycoolness.a`. If you distribute `libmycoolness.a` to your customers, they will have to jump through the `CC` and `FIPSLD_CC` hoops.

---

If you don't want to jump through the `CC` and `FIPSLD_CC` hoops, then you should link against fipscanister.o and run `incore` manually after building you executable or shared object. The OpenSSL folks don't recommend this, however. They recommend using `CC` and `FIPSLD_CC`.

**Note**: you do not compile `fips_premain.c` yourself.

---

If `fips_premain.c` pukes an error when trying to build the FIPS Object Module, then your platform is not supported. You should contact Steve Marquess of the OpenSSL Foundation and schedule a talk about validating the platform. See [*OpenSSL and FIPS 140-2*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html) and [*OpenSSL FIPS 140-2 Security Policy*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.pdf).

---

Related, if you are getting undefined symbols due to C++ name decoration, then check out [`Fipsld and C++`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Fipsld_and_C%2B%2B) on the OpenSSL wiki.

The solution is to modify `fipsld`. Its not a sequestered source, so you can modify it within reason. In this case, `fipsld++` effectively performs the following when it compiles `fips_premain.c` for you:

```
${CC}  ${CANISTER_O_CMD:+"${CANISTER_O_CMD}"} \
    -x c "${PREMAIN_C}" -x none \
    ${_WL_PREMAIN} "$@"
```

The change is effectivly the addition of the `${CC} -x c fips_premain.c -x none ...` when compiling `fips_premain.c`.

Comment: It looks like you are saying I need to use gcc to compile my_library_with_static_140_2_openssl.so.  Could you provide a link to a FIPS or OpenSSL document that says this?  I know using gcc would work, but I can not use that as a reason to switch our compiler.

Comment: Tyler - my bad. You don't need to use GCC to compile your library. That's an area where you are allowed to turn knobs.

(I would have to talk to Steve Marquess *if* the question was "do I have to compile OpenSSL FIPS Object Module with GCC". That question falls into the grey area of "what's a platform" in the context of FIPS 140-2 and software modules).